# Use google map support fragment in fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am currently doing an application with my main activity as a NavigationDrawer. So, to navigate through my application any other "activity" is a fragment and, in one of thoses fragment I need to put a GoogleMap support fragment. The point is that when, in my fragment, I do `getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);` it returns null.

Here is what my code looks like.

```
//fragment_home.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
//My HomeFragment
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}
```

Do anyone have an idea on how to fix this? I already looked for solutions on this website and many others but I can't figure how to get the fragment stored in the xml layout of my "parent" fragment.

Thanks for your help,
Cordially,
Matthieu Meunier

Answer (score 3):

If you are to use a `SupportMapFragment` inside a `Fragment` you can't use `getFragmentManager` method. Instead use the following method.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```